# Scrolling canvas doesn't scroll

Tags: scroll, tkinter-canvas

I have subclassed a TkInter canvas and added a scroll bar.
I have created a number of images as content.
Everything displays as expected, but the scroll bar does nothing.
Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?
Many thanks
karl

```
class MapElements(Canvas):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)

        self.scroll_y = Scrollbar(master, orien="vertical", command=self.yview)
       
        self.scroll_y.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="ns")

        self.configure(yscrollcommand=self.scroll_y.set)

        label = CTkLabel(self, text="Ground", anchor="nw")
        label.place(x=20, y=20)

        files = os.listdir(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "uf_split", "uf_terrain"))
        files.sort()

        i = 0
        x = 20
        y = 60

        self.images = []
        self.buttons = []
        for filename in files:

            image = Image.open(
                os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "uf_split", "uf_terrain", filename)
            )
            self.images.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(image))
            self.buttons.append(CTkLabel(self, image=self.images[i], width=48))
            self.buttons[i].place(x=x, y=y)
            i += 1
            x += 50
            if x > (50 * 5):
                y += 50
                x = 20

        self.configure(scrollregion=self.bbox("all"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I realise what I was doing wrong.
I was trying to place things using label widgets inside a canvas.
I should have been using 'create_text' and 'create_rectangle'
thanks